# Cannot allocate array - overflow on array size calculation

Tags: fortran

I need to import a txt file (size: 2^N ; dimension: 1.4 GB) in Fortran and save it in an array: DATI. Starting from that, I have to generate a matrix with N columns equals to DATI: MATPAYOFF. In the specific case N=26 (reals are in double precision). I use Visual Studio 2013 on a 64-bit machine (Intel Xeon CPU E5-1650 v2 @3.50GHz, Ram: 24.0 GHz, Windows 10 Pro).

```
ALLOCATE(MATPAYOFF(1:2**N,1:N),DATI(1:2**N),VECPAYOFF(1:2**N))

CALL read_file(UNITA,'RandomData_N_'//TRIM(str(N))//'_file_'//TRIM(str(LAMBDA))//'.txt',2**N,1,DATI)

FORALL(j=1:N)
       MATPAYOFF(:,j)=DATI
ENDFORALL

VECPAYOFF=(DATI-MINVAL(DATI))/(MAXVAL(DATI)-MINVAL(DATI))
```

During the allocate statement I get the following error: "***forrtl: severe (179): Cannot allocate array - overflow on array size calculation***" I tried to solve it imposing:

In the machine: the dimension of the paging file to 20000 MB.

In Visual Studio: Project/Propriety/ Fortran/ Optimization/Heap Arrays: 0.

In Visual Studio: Project/Propriety/ Fortran/ Command Line: /heap_arrays.

How may I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show your compiler options. Are you using a 64bit compiler?

Comment: Also see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/269131)

Comment: Edited out the Fortran 90. Your code is not Fortran 90. There is no `FORALL` in Fortran 90, it was added later.

Comment: I try to solve in this way, after your suggestion, but for N>23 the problem persist. `MODULE Kinds
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: long_integer = 8
ENDMODULE Kinds ALLOCATE(MATPAYOFF(1_long_integer:2_long_integer**N,1_long_integer:N))`

Comment: It's likely more to be the implementation's address/size calculations, rather than overflow in your `2**26`: 2^26*2^4.7*2^4 requires a larger than 2GiB array.  Perhaps there's an option around maximum array sizes?  [I'm not a user of Intel Fortran on Windows.]

Comment: Might be related to mcmodel-ish thing? (and the error message seems very similar to that in Alexander's link above!)